# Converting a list

Tags: python

I have a list similar to the one shown below. Do you have any ideas on how I can convert it to the one in the **EXPECTED OUTPUT** section below?

```
list =['username1,username2', 'username3','username4,username5']
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:-**

```
list = ['username1','username2', 'username3','username4','username5']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> alist = ['username1,username2', 'username3','username4,username5']
>>> ','.join(alist).split(',')
['username1', 'username2', 'username3', 'username4', 'username5']
```

By the way, don't use `list` as the variable name.

Comment: This is around 3x as fast as Jared's solution, kudos.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use

```
>>> alist = ['username1,username2', 'username3','username4,username5']
>>> [j for i in alist for j in i.split(',')]
```

but @zhangyangyu's method is faster

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("[j for i in ['username1,username2', 'username3','username4,us
ername5'] for j in i.split(',')]", number=10000)
0.05875942333452144
>>> timeit.timeit("','.join(['username1,username2', 'username3','username4,usern
ame5']).split(',')", number=10000)
0.023530085527625033
```